# Azure batch insert - how to reduce response length?

Tags: azure, batch-processing, azure-table-storage, azure-batch

I use Azure client lib to perform batch inserts into Azure Table Storage. Everything works fine. But when I sniff requests using Fiddler I found that every response from azure is about 90KB. I've changed prefer header to "return-no-content", but the response is still over 60KB (when request is 50KB).

Is there any way to reduce response lenght? Just to be like 100B (HTTP 202 or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per OData V3 protocol format that Azure Storage Table Service uses, a batch response body must structurally match one-to-one with the corresponding batch request body, such that the same multipart MIME message structure defined for requests is used for responses.

Setting echoContent to false (aka "Prefer: return-no-content") would ensure that entities themselves are not returned though as you also observed, therefore reducing the size of the response body.